# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 jsonrpc library

Tags: c++, json, qt, build, symbols

I have some hardtime compiling an application with QT using the jsonRpc library : 
 - [libjson-rpc-cpp](https://github.com/cinemast/libjson-rpc-cpp) 
 - [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp)
When compiling, I have this error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
Json::Value::operator=(Json::Value const&)", referenced from:
  jsonrpc::RpcProtocolServerV1::WrapException(Json::Value const&, jsonrpc::JsonRpcException const&, Json::Value&) in libjson-rpc-cpp.a(rpcprotocolserverv1.o)
  jsonrpc::RpcProtocolServerV1::WrapResult(Json::Value const&, Json::Value&, Json::Value&) in libjson-rpc-cpp.a(rpcprotocolserverv1.o)
  jsonrpc::RpcProtocolServerV1::WrapError(Json::Value const&, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, Json::Value&) in libjson-rpc-cpp.a(rpcprotocolserverv1.o)
  jsonrpc::RpcProtocolServerV2::WrapException(Json::Value const&, jsonrpc::JsonRpcException const&, Json::Value&) in libjson-rpc-cpp.a(rpcprotocolserverv2.o)
  jsonrpc::RpcProtocolServerV2::WrapResult(Json::Value const&, Json::Value&, Json::Value&) in libjson-rpc-cpp.a(rpcprotocolserverv2.o)
  jsonrpc::RpcProtocolServerV2::WrapError(Json::Value const&, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, Json::Value&) in libjson-rpc-cpp.a(rpcprotocolserverv2.o)
  jsonrpc::AbstractProtocolHandler::ProcessRequest(Json::Value const&, Json::Value&) in libjson-rpc-cpp.a(abstractprotocolhandler.o)
  ...
```

I try to find in value.h the definition of the overload = operator and I find this :

```
Value& operator=(Value other);
```

It's probably something to do with a linker issue, but I really don't know how to resolve it..
Can anyone please give me some help with this ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the version of libjson-rpc-cpp.a was compile with a non update source of jsoncpp library. So I re-generate a libjson-rpc-cpp.a updated and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when compiling OSVR. The source of the problem was outdated jsoncpp headers in /usr/local/include.

What worked for me:

- Remove jsoncpp from /usr/local/lib, /usr/local/include
- Remove libjson-rpc-cpp from /usr/local/lib, /usr/local/include

Build and install jsoncpp, including dynamic library, from github source:

- git clone --recursive https://github.com/VRPN/jsoncpp
- git clone --recursive https://github.com/cinemast/libjson-rpc-cpp.git
- cd jsoncpp
- cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug -DBUILD_STATIC_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DARCHIVE_INSTALL_DIR=. -G "Unix Makefiles" .
- make
- make install
- cd ../libjson-rpc-cpp
- cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug -DBUILD_STATIC_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DARCHIVE_INSTALL_DIR=. -G "Unix Makefiles" .
- make
- make install